# How do I downgrade the Flash player on OS X?

Tags: macos, flash, flash-player, downgrade

I need to downgrade to the most previous version of the Adobe Flash Player version 10 that is in use by Safari.

How can I do this?

To clarify, I need the previous version of Flash Player 10. There are numerous sub-versions....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [internets](http://www.tuesdaynight.org/2008/10/28/downgrading-to-flash-9-for-mac-os-x.html):

> - Download the Flash Uninstaller from Adobe – [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html)
> - Fix Disk Permissions via the Disk Utility
> - Download all whole slew of versions of Flash 9 – [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14266.html).
> - Fix Disk Permissions via the Disk Utility

To fix the disk permissions, just open up Disk Utility, select "Macintosh HD" (or whatever the  name of the OS X partition is, click the "First Aid" tab, then the "Repair Disk Permissions" button:

[image]

Comment: argh, beat me with same links!

Comment: What does 'Fix Disk Permissions via the Disk Utility' mean? Sorry, I'm a Mac noob trying to help a client. :/

Answer (score 0):

I can not really say 100% for mac, however I recently had to support this for PC.

If Safari comes pre-installed / comes with Flash, this may not help.

[Take a look here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html) I just found this on Adobe, however I have not tried it, it describes how to uninstall Flash on Apple.

Uninstall or disable and remove flash.

[Take a look at this site](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14266.html)

It does not have EVERY minor release of flash, but it does have every Major release along with a few of the minors for each one - Each version comes with Linux, Mac and Windows setups.